# Color the first visible cell on top in an UITableView after scrolling

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want that always the first visible cell in my UITableView has a different background color than the other cells.

**Currently I have this for my UITableView**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 100
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableViewNew.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellNewPosts", for: indexPath) as! MainNewTableViewCell

    return cell
    }
```

**And this, so the first cell is snapped to the top. So technically, I have the row which should be colored (currentItemOnTop):**

```
scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

    // Vibration Feedback
    let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
    generator.impactOccurred()

    guard var scrollingToIP = tableViewNew.indexPathForRow(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: targetContentOffset.pointee.y)) else {
        return
    }

    var scrollingToRect = tableViewNew.rectForRow(at: scrollingToIP)
    let roundingRow = Int(((targetContentOffset.pointee.y - scrollingToRect.origin.y) / scrollingToRect.size.height).rounded())

    scrollingToIP.row += roundingRow
    scrollingToRect = tableViewNew.rectForRow(at: scrollingToIP)
    targetContentOffset.pointee.y = scrollingToRect.origin.y

    currentItemOnTop = scrollingToIP.row

}
```

How can I achieve this? I tried a lot of stuff, but I think my problem is that I am using reusable cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty easy, in `cellForRow` assign the color depending on `currentItemOnTop`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableViewNew.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellNewPosts", for: indexPath) as! MainNewTableViewCell
   if indexPath.row == currentItemOnTop {
      cell.backgroundColor = .systemRed
   } else {
      cell.backgroundColor = // specify a default color
   }
   return cell
}
```

In `scrollViewWillEndDragging` reload the previous and current rows after updating the property

```
scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    // Vibration Feedback
    let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
    generator.impactOccurred()
    guard var scrollingToIP = tableViewNew.indexPathForRow(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: targetContentOffset.pointee.y)) else {
        return
    }
    var scrollingToRect = tableViewNew.rectForRow(at: scrollingToIP)
    let roundingRow = Int(((targetContentOffset.pointee.y - scrollingToRect.origin.y) / scrollingToRect.size.height).rounded())
    scrollingToIP.row += roundingRow
    scrollingToRect = tableViewNew.rectForRow(at: scrollingToIP)
    targetContentOffset.pointee.y = scrollingToRect.origin.y
    let previousRow = currentItemOnTop
    currentItemOnTop = scrollingToIP.row
    let indexPaths = [IndexPath(row: previousRow, section: 0), IndexPath(row: currentItemOnTop, section: 0)]
    tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPaths, with: .none)

}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time. It has some very weird behaviour now, but I got your idea.